# Measure based on an email sent in journey builder where entry is a salesforce campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a journey where the client would like to add subscribers via sales cloud (no problem), And based on their tracking we are gonna do x amount of actions. Normally I would create a filter based on a measure from the specific emails.. clicks etc. However the measure However it seems like I cant create my filter based on the campaign or "All subscribers(where they are added if they recieve an email)

**IS there any way I can create a filter based on a measure for example on "all subscribers" OR the campaign they entered through?**

Bonus info: 
We are only pulling in subscribers that have accepted emails to sfmc, and since this is a double optin journey they are not being added to the master data extension before they have accepted the email sent in the journey.

Hope it makes sense, otherwise let me know, stay safe!

Best Martin

Comment: Can you explain your question a little further? It is a little difficult to understand what exactly you're asking. Are you asking for tracking information for the emails within the journey?

Comment: Hi @Nick, 
sure thing! 
Basically I'm looking for a way to do a measure on profiles added to a journey through a salesforce campaign. Since they are not added to be a part of the datamodel I cant seem to find a way to create a measure based on the entry. But as far as I can read in the documentation the way out is an SQL based on data views.

Comment: ah wait. I can see that sfmc creates a data extension, based on the journey. problem solved!